# Simple calculator in java

Tags: java, calculator

I'm trying to create simple calculator in java with user input for first number and second number and then with while loop calculate as user like
but when I wrote for example **a** instead of sum two number it broke loop!!
why?

```
package com.myproject.CalcEngine2;
import java.util.Scanner; // import the Scanner class

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter fisr number");
        double val1 = myObj.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter fisr number");
        double val2 = myObj.nextDouble();
        double result = 0.0d;
        String addition = "a";
        System.out.println("Enter what you want to do");
        String opCode = myObj.next();
        while(opCode.equals("E")) {
            if (opCode.equals(addition))
                result = val1 + val2;
            else if (opCode.equals("s"))
                result = val1 - val2;
            else if (opCode.equals("d"))
                result = val1 / val2;
            else if (opCode.equals("m"))
                result = val1 * val2;
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("Enter what you want to do"+"E for exit , a for addition , s for subtraction , d for Division , m for multiplication ");
            opCode = myObj.next();
        }
    }
}
```

program shows for every char that I wrote it will be false but I can't understand why!?

Comment: `while(opCode.equals("E")) {` should be `while(!opCode.equals("E")) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you have entered ,

```
while(opCode.equals("E")){

}
```

is not correct for this scenario. It will not be executed the block inside while loop, until you input `E`.
**So, Then none of your if else conditions satisfy**.

Adding,

```
 while(!opCode.equals("E")){

}
```

for the code will help you.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps because the while loop will terminate except for "E"?

```
while(opCode.equals("E")) {
```

only runs when it "E" but I think you mean

```
while(!opCode.equals("E")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the condition in the while loop, it terminates if the **entered input is not 'E'**.

To make it work change as follows:

```
while(!opCode.equals("E")) {
// Operation code
}
```

BTW, to be more clear with the operations, you can print as below:

```
System.out.println("Enter what you want to do, 'a': for addition, 's': for subtraction, 'd': for division, 'm': for multiplication ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all
And here you are final code for who will search in future with remove case sensitivity!

```
package com.myprogram.CalcEngine;
import java.util.Scanner; // import the Scanner class

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter fisr number");
        double val1 = myObj.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter fisr number");
        double val2 = myObj.nextDouble();
        double result = 0.0d;
        String addition = "a";
        System.out.println("Enter what you want to do");
        String opCode = myObj.next().toLowerCase();
        while(!opCode.equals("e")) {
            if (opCode.equals(addition)){
                result = val1 + val2;
                System.out.println(result);}
            else if (opCode.equals("s")){
                result = val1 - val2;
                System.out.println(result);}
            else if (opCode.equals("d")){
                result = val1 / val2;
                System.out.println(result);}
            else if (opCode.equals("m")){
                result = val1 * val2;
                System.out.println(result);}
            else
                System.out.println("Error please enter true character: ");
            System.out.println("Enter what you want to do"+"E for exit , a for addition , s for subtraction , d for Division , m for multiplication ");
            opCode = myObj.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Good bye! See you :) ");
    }
}
```

with change

```
String opCode = myObj.next();
```

to

```
String opCode = myObj.next().toLowerCase();
```

in line 15 and 
change

```
opCode = myObj.next();
```

to

```
opCode = myObj.next().toLowerCase();
```

in line 32

All the input will be lowercase.
All the best.